# addEventListener doesn´t forward argument

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I added a `.on("contextmenu", contextMenu)` function to my D3v4 forced graph. The contextMenu appears and I can choose different options. Also the first console output `console.log(d.name)` fires the expected result.

But as soon as I choose a context option like `..addEventListener("click", search);` and fire again the same console output, I receive an error that `d is not defined`. If I change the addEventListner to `..addEventListener("click", search(d));` it doesn´t work either.

Any idea?

```
 function contextMenu(d) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var contextElement = document.getElementById("context-menu");
        contextElement.style.left = event.x + "px";
        contextElement.style.top = event.y + "px";
        contextElement.classList.add("active");

        //FIRST OUTPUT DURING CONTEXT ENTER
        console.log(d.name)
    }

    window.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("context-menu").classList.remove("active");
    })

    // listener and code to search a object 
    document.getElementById("searchObject").addEventListener("click", search);

    function search(d) {
        //SECOND OUTPUT "D IS NOT DEFINED ERROR"
        console.log(d.name)
    }
```

Comment: When attaching an event listener with `.addEventListener("click", search);`, the event argument is passed to `search`, unless d3.js rewrite the native `addEventListener` method.

Comment: When your search function runs, because it's handling a click event the parameter it receives is a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), it doesn't matter if you call that parameter `d` or any other name, it's a MouseEvent.  If you want a reference to `d`, whatever that is (your d3 chart?), you should declare it somewhere globally and then just use that variable inside your click function.

Comment: @James It's odd, that the code triggers an error, it should just log `undefined`. @ICoded, I doubt you're calling `search` somewhere without the parameter ..?

Comment: Your code above produces undefined.  The error you mention is if you use addEventListener("click", search(d)).

Comment: Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/mL197bpc/, exaclty I got undefined as a log. I actually want the d.name attribute as a test. I thought I can create a contextMenu and if I click on an d3 element, those functions will somehow be valid for this element.

Comment: @ICoded so what is `d` supposed to be?

Comment: You can't. The native event passes the native event object, d3.js events are creating their own event object to pass to the callback functions.

Comment: @Teemu means I need to stuck with the ugly d3.event contextMenu functions? Urghs..

Comment: @James d represents this element from the node array above. Like the clicked one, similar to the drag functions.

Comment: Yes, they are built to work with d3.js. That `on` function makes a lot of things behind the scenes, it's not just a simple event attacher function.

Comment: OK I see the problem.  Your searchObject is a html element and the rest of your code is working with svg objects.  So the click handlers are completely different.